# divide a php expression for further

Tags: php

I need to divide in 2 part this expression (or other expression with a logical operator) provided by user to use it like a string (not to be interpret by php):

```
(($var == 'pagina' or strpos($var,'page')!==false) or ($var == 'article' or strpos($var,'article')!==false)) and !strstr($var,'test')
```

the two part should be:

```
$var == 'page' or strpos($var,'page')!==false or $var == 'article' or strpos($var,'article')!==false
```

and

```
!strstr($var,'test')
```

any ideas?

Comment: So what did you try ? Why would you need anything like that?

Comment: Great question. I have to convert the string in one array to make the expression editable by user